# Problem in CSV file : Delimiter and column title declaration

Tags: c#, csv

I open a .csv File in my code and I wish to give a delimiter of my choice and define columns(title names).i need to know how to define them. I use the following way to generate my file:

```
fnresultfile = new StreamWriter("Resultfile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".csv", true); //Filename

fnresultfile.WriteLine("Data recorded on date : " + DateTime.Now);  
fnresultfile.WriteLine("The parameters of this Test Sequence were set to :");
fnresultfile.WriteLine("X =" + Xactual + ",Y =" + Yactual + ",Z =" + Zactual);
fnresultfile.WriteLine("Key Orientation = " + Key_OrientationBox.Text);

fnresultfile.Close();
```

Comment: You wrote there's a problem - what is it?

Comment: The file's format doesn't seem ti be a CSV (Comma Separated Values) but rather `name = value`

Comment: What is the desired file format, please?

Comment: The way I have written is different from what I see on the forums. But this too generates  a csv file , but I dont know how to give delimiter and Column titles .

Comment: The way the column titles are build up with data is not the way a csv is used. A csv is build up like a table, see my answer below.

Comment: What is the purpose of the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is just a text file. 
With the convention/agreement that it holds data in rows with records, which are seperated by a comma (',' or ';'). With or without a header (title).

So, you can add the column titles just as you add the data in your example.
And the delimiters you can also add as a variable, just as you added the data.

Not sure if your example is writing the column titles.
If so, there is an example below. You can change the string array to first build up the data with a StringBuilder for example.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

// Based on an example from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string delimitor = ",";

        // Create a string array with the lines of text
        string[] lines = 
        { 
           $"data record 1,data record 2,data record 3,data record 4", // First data line
           $"data record 1,data record 2,data record 3,data record 4", // Second data line
           $"data record 1,data record 2,data record 3,data record 4"  // Third data line
        };

        var filename = "Resultfile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".csv"

        // Set a variable to the Documents path.
        string docPath =
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        // Write the string array to a new file named "WriteLines.txt".
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, filename)))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
                outputFile.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The result would be:

```
Data recorded on date,The parameters of this Test Sequence were set to,X,Key Orientation
data record 1,data record 2,data record 3,data record 4
data record 1,data record 2,data record 3,data record 4
data record 1,data record 2,data record 3,data record 4
```

Answer (score -2):

Use string.Join() method :

```
           string[] line = { 
                                "Data recorded on date : " + DateTime.Now, 
                                "The parameters of this Test Sequence were set to :",
                                "X =" + Xactual + ",Y =" + Yactual + ",Z =" + Zactual,
                                "Key Orientation = " + Key_OrientationBox.Text,
                            };
            string separator = ",";

            fnresultfile.WriteLine(string.Join(separator,line));
            fnresultfile.Close();
```

Comment: This just reformats what OP posted and doesn't answer the question (to be fair OP didn't actually ask a question though.)

Comment: The question was : "give a delimiter of my choice"

Comment: I think OP was talking about the commas/delimiters in `"X =" + Xactual + ",Y =" + Yactual + ",Z =" + Zactual` but also said CSV which this isn't.